# How to implement Anvato SDK?

Tags: android, tvos, roku, amazon-fire-tv

I want to implement Anvato SDK for playing ads. After some R&D I found Platform SDKs description from "https://dev.anvato.net/", 
there Anvato SDK have briefly described only, we have not found any SDK pakage or demo code, that could implementation our platforms 
(tvOS , Roku , Android TV).

Comment: Same issue with me unable to find any link to download .jar or .aar or gradle for Anvato Android SDK...

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with the Anvato SDK's before. The Anvato Mobile SDK's are to be used in conjunction with their other products, such as their media content platform and Anvato backend services. I think if you just want to play ads, you would be better off using base video players such as ExoPlayer for Android, AVPlayer for iOS/TvOS, etc.

ExoPlayer:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

AVPlayer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

While it is nice to see interest in our products, the SDK's aren't meant to be used to play ads or videos on their own. The SDKs are designed to be used by our customers, who use the Anvato Media Control Platform to manage content. We do not plan to support our SDKs as stand alone video players for now.